# Make authorized request to Google Endpoint API from Android Client

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I need to identify user who made request to my endpoint api, via Android client. Though I am able to follow best practice by keeping my Api and App within one project using gradle and android studio. Also I am able to send request to my endpoint api and receive response without authorization.

Basically I need to send authorization token as header in the request, people suggest that, merely by adding instance of "GoogleAccountCredential" along with the request will do the trick as in the code below. The class in which below code is present that extends android.os.AsyncTask; I have been following https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#using_the_account_picker, but code fragments are not very clear.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
..
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), credential).setRootUrl("https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
..
```

**What I have :**

1. I have an Activity called ExpandedListViewActivity
2. another thing is ExpandedListAdaptor, which populates views dynamically ( form ).

**My Objective**

3. When User clicks on submit present in the form.
4. Android should be able to find the google account and its credentials and attach it with the request.
5. If it does not find then show account selector view, so that user can select account, if we can do it silently without user consent that would be very nice.

Extra methods that I have in :

> class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask, Void,
>   String>

```
void chooseAccount() {
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }

    protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
            // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
            userRecoverableException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
            // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
            // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.

        }
        return null;
    }


    public void getSettings(){
        Log.d(APP, "get Settings ");
        settings = mActivity.getSharedPreferences("Api", 0);

        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(mActivity,
                "server:client_id:Android-clientId.apps.googleusercontent.com");
        setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
    }

    // setSelectedAccountName definition
    private void setSelectedAccountName(String accountName) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
        editor.commit();
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }
```

Please take into account that my endpoint server side is properly configured and running.
It should be straight forward, but I am not able to solve this, Please point the mistake or show me a direction to solve this..

Thanks for reading.
Shashank

Comment: Android experts, please help.

Comment: In the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls      What does "TicTacToeSample" represent here, is it API Name ? 
settings = getSharedPreferences("TicTacToeSample", 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

1. Specify the client IDs (clientIds) of apps authorized to make requests to your API backend.
2. Add a User parameter to all exposed methods to be protected by authorization.
3. Generate the client library again for any Android clients
4. **Redeploy your backend API.** <-- This was the key, to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Shashank